# Difference between PHP Associative Array value assignment methods

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, associative-array

I am building a PHP based web application that uses AJAX calls for CRUD. while designing the FETCH.php pages I come around two types of situations while looping and assigning values to Associative Arrays in PHP. I cannot understand the need and difference of usage between these two types of values assignments

**METHOD # 1** (This method will give Plain JSON format (Containing that specific record) and no looping in JQuery is needed and values can directly be assigned to DOM Element by JQuery Object notation. I use this method to call values in Form Elements from the Database when a specific record is called).

```
$output = [];
while ($Datarows = $stmt->fetch()) {

 $output['app_id']  = $Datarows['app_id']; // FOCUS HERE PLEASE.

}
echo json_encode($output, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

**METHOD # 2** (This method will output a JSON ARRAY when checked in brower NETWORK tab. The array needs to be looped thru with in JQuery. I use this method for Creating Dependent Dropdown Boxes to several levels.)

```
$output = [];
while ($Datarows = $stmt->fetch()) {
        
      $app_id   = $Datarows['app_id'];
      $output[] = ['app_id' => $app_id];
 }
 echo json_encode($output,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

I cannot understand the exact difference between the two approaches. Please Elaborate.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The first is more correct than the second. Please see the examples at https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php Also read the comments. Be aware that this is something of an objective question and may get down voted. https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: How can I amend it to involve Research intent. Thanks

Comment: you should be to Edit your post. You can then add your intent.

Comment: Method #1 overwrites `$output['app_id']` each time through the loop, so even if you have 100 `$Datarows` the `$output` will only have one element.  So what is the real question?

Comment: @AbraCadaver you further cleared my concept. you are right. The Question was that I could not understand the difference of output between the two approaches. now I am clear. The method 1 is only useful when i need a specific record called by a specific ID. The Method 2 will give me all the bunch of data which I can manipulate further. Please second my comment if I am right. Thanks

Comment: Yes, but you would only do method 1 if you know there is only one record and so would not use a `while` loop, just `$output['app_id'] = $stmt->fetch()['app_id'];` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example:

```
<?php
// Assign Arrays to Varibales
$a1 = array();
$a2 = [];

// Assing String to Array
$a1['foo'] = "bar";
$a1['zoo'] = "car";
var_export($a1);
echo "<br />";

// Assign Array to Array (no association)
$a2[] = ['foo' => "bar"];
array_push($a2, "car");
var_export($a2);
?>
```

You would see the following output:

```
array ( 'foo' => 'bar', 'zoo' => 'car', )
array ( 0 => array ( 'foo' => 'bar', ), 1 => 'car', )
```

You can see it is a vastly different assignment. What type of array are you trying to create? This will define which assignment you will want to use.

For your code, I would advise the following.

```
$output = [];
while ($Datarows = $stmt->fetch()) {
  array_push($output, $Datarows['app_id']);
}
echo json_encode($output, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

This will gather just the `app_id` elements from the `$Datarows` array and push them into the `$output` array. You will now have an Array of App IDs.

If you want an Array of Associated Elements, you can do this:

```
$output = [];
while ($Datarows = $stmt->fetch()) {
  array_push($output, array('app_id' => $Datarows['app_id']));
}
echo json_encode($output, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

A similar example:

```
<?php
$Datarows = array(
  ["app_id" => 1001],
  ["app_id" => 1002],
  ["app_id" => 1003],
  ["app_id" => 1004],
  ["app_id" => 1005],
  ["app_id" => 1006]
);

$output = array();
foreach($Datarows as $row){
  array_push($output, array("app_id" => $row['app_id']));
}
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

You get the following JSON:

```
[{"app_id":1001},{"app_id":1002},{"app_id":1003},{"app_id":1004},{"app_id":1005},{"app_id":1006}]
```

Comment: Your examples cleared thing. basically the second method i am doing is not resulting in associative array but simply an auto indexed array. I am getting Array with in Array in the form of JSON. Then I have to loop thru. Got it. Thanks Man.

Comment: @FKB Great. You're welcome to mark it as the Answer. In the future you will also be able to Upvote.